# Need suggestions to create a chat application

Tags: c#, asp.net

This question may sound stupid. I need suggestions from you guys to create a chat application using asp.net.  The thing where I am confused is that there are many techniques in asp.net such as MVC, AJAX and many more (I dont know about them, been aware through many tutorial sites). So I dont know which technique to use. I will just explain the chat application which I am creating to you guys so that you can give some suggestions:

> -- It should be just like gmail chat application
>   -- The chat messages should be stored in a Database
>   -- There should be two tabs, one for important chat and other for casual chat (Both should be store in database)
>   -- This chat application will be integrated to existing website.

So, my question is simple which technique of asp.net should I use to make it more efficient(or simple to understand). I am a trainee and I have only visual studio 2010. (This is my main project) The things I know are Basics of ASP.net, ado.net, c#.net, jquery, css, html and javascript.

Comment: Dont close I will delete this question, If it sounds not good.

Comment: you should rethink your decision about having 2 tables for chat storage... one more column would be enough to tell the entries apart

Comment: This not my idea, it is the assignment given by my head member.

Comment: then read about database normalization and tell him/her why redundancy is bad ...

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 Ok thankyou for this suggestion. if you saying that much then I will make him convince to keep one tab. But which technique should I go with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'd suggest you should have a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net) ... and [one of the projects done with it](http://fczaja.blogspot.de/2012/09/the-simplest-chat-ever-with-signalr-and.html) ...

Comment: I am new to all this. I hope these all are not premium services and can be integrated with visual studio 2010. right ?

Comment: SignalR is available under Apache License 2.0 if i remember correctly...

Answer (score 3):

For the Web instant messaging feature:

- Consider using [reverse Ajax / comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) techniques (if you need compatibility with old not [HTML5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) browsers). That technique is a mix of javascript and server side code. But there are libs ready (see below).
- or [WebSocket for .NET](http://www.paulbatum.com/2011/10/getting-to-know-systemnetwebsockets.html) if browser compatibility is not an issue.

The following .NET library seems to support both: [Pokein](http://pokein.com/)

Hope that help.

P.S.

if you want really to scale, then probably you need to get rid of the database and probably use some external chat server system like [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/)

Comment: I am new to all this. I hope these all are not premium services and can be integrated with visual studio 2010. right ?

Comment: rev ajax/comet is a technique not an artifact/service (click link for wiki def). HTML5 is a specification that new browser implements, part of that spec is websocket (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket, click the links for details). Websocket for .net is part of .net I think since v.4 (click the link above). Openfire is open source but is only if you need a large scale system. Pokein seems to have a community edition. But there are a lot of open source libraries implementing the two techniques (websocket and rev ajax). Google for ".net reverse ajax" or ".net websocket")

Comment: ok thank you, and sorry I was confused.